# Merge 2 variables vertically R tidyverse

Tags: r, tidy

I conducted a survey in 2 languages and I want to combine the questions in the 2 languages into one variable.

The answers of the form are all in the same `data.frame`. The date is my primary key. Unfortunately I am still new to R and could not find how to elegantly combine these.

Example As Is situation

| Date | Place_English | Plane_English | Place_French | Plane_French |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One |  |  | azea | Three |
| Two | ertert | ertt |  |  |

To Be

| Date | Place | Plane |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | azea | Three |
| Two | ertert | ertt |

Comment: Have a look at `coalesce`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :) I think this will not work in my case because there are some missing values in the set of questions in 1 language.

Comment: Are you blanks emptry strings `''` or `NA`?

Comment: The empty blanks are NA.

Comment: That's pretty much what `coalesce` does really well - it ignores the first NAs until it finds a non-NA value and returns that one. See my example below. The tricky bit is that there are some warnings with factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `paste` if you dont want lose any data

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% mutate(Place = paste(Place_English, Place_French),
             Plane = paste(Plane_English, Plane_French),
             across(Place_English:Plane_French, ~NULL)) ## last line to remove unnecessary columns
```

or `coalesce` if you want to get rid of `NA`s

```
df%>% mutate(Place = coalesce(Place_English, Place_French),
             Plane = coalesce(Plane_English, Plane_French),
             across(Place_English:Plane_French, ~NULL)) ## last line to remove unnecessary columns
```

---

if you want combine more than 2 cols, use `unite` from `tidyr`. set `na.rm` according to your preferences

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  unite("Place", colnames(df)[grepl(pattern = "Place", colnames(df))] , remove = T, sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE) %>%  ## all cols including "Place" in name
  unite("Plane", colnames(df)[grepl(pattern = "Plane", colnames(df))] , remove = T, sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE) ## all cols including "Plane" in name
```

```
library(tidyr)
cols_to_paste <- colnames(df[,]) ## to choose only sepecified cols i.e. df[,15:25] or df[,c(15,18,20,25)]

df %>% 
  unite('Place', cols_to_paste[grepl(pattern = 'Place', cols_to_paste)] , remove = T, sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE) %>% ## all cols including "Place" in name
  unite('Plane', cols_to_paste[grepl(pattern = 'Plane', cols_to_paste)] , remove = T, sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE) ## all cols including "Plane" in name
```

Comment: If I don't want to lose data, is there a way to do this without having to name all the columns myself?

Comment: which columns do you mean?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, in the case there are way more columns originating from my survey, and not only 2 as in this example. For example in a way that columns 25:35 are ppasted under columns 15:25

Comment: editted. check if this is what you are looking for. otherwise, lets chat about this

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up on my comment, assuming the empty values are NAs:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Creating the data:

```
df <- data.frame(place_english = c(NA, "ertert"), 
                 plane_english = c(NA, "ertt"), 
                 place_french = c("azea", NA), 
                 plane_french=c("Three", NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Using coalesce to replace NAs with the first non-NA values:

```
df %>% mutate(Plane = coalesce(plane_english, plane_french),
              Place = coalesce(place_english, place_french),
             )
Source: local data frame [2 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  place_english plane_english place_french plane_french Plane Place 
  <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        <chr>        <chr> <chr> 
1 NA            NA            azea         Three        Three azea  
2 ertert        ertt          NA           NA           ertt  ertert
```

You could also achieve the same for one column at a time using e.g.

```
df$Place <- coalesce(df$place_english, df$place_french)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, list(~na_if(.,""))) %>% #only needed if the missing fields are stored as blanks and not already NA
  transmute(
    Date,
    Place = coalesce(Place_English, Place_French),
    Plane = coalesce(Plane_English, Plane_French)
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches, both using `dplyr`

**Case-1: If NA/missing values are there**

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Date   Place_English   Plane_English   Place_French    Plane_French
One NA NA   azea    Three
Two ertert  ertt    NA NA   ")

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_English'), ~ coalesce(., get(gsub('_English', '_French', cur_column()))),
                   .names = "{gsub('_English', '', .col)}"), .keep = 'unused')
#>   Date  Place Plane
#> 1  One   azea Three
#> 2  Two ertert  ertt
```

---

**case-2: if there are empty strings instead**

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Date   Place_English   Plane_English   Place_French    Plane_French
One '' ''   azea    Three
Two ertert  ertt    ''  ''  ")
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('_English'), ~ paste0(., get(gsub('_English', '_French', cur_column()))),
                   .names = "{gsub('_English', '', .col)}"), .keep = 'unused')
#>   Date  Place Plane
#> 1  One   azea Three
#> 2  Two ertert  ertt
```

Answer (score 3):

In case there are >2 columns and you don't want to type them all, you can use same approach as @coffeinjunky, but with `across`

```r
df <- data.frame(place_english = c(NA, "ertert"), 
                 plane_english = c(NA, "ertt"), 
                 place_french = c("azea", NA), 
                 plane_french=c("Three", NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>% 
  transmute(place = do.call(coalesce, across(starts_with('place'))), 
            plane = do.call(coalesce, across(starts_with('plane'))))
#>    place plane
#> 1   azea Three
#> 2 ertert  ertt
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R approach using `split.default` which should work dynamically for any number of groups.

```
tmp <- df[-1]

result <- cbind(df[1], sapply(split.default(tmp, sub('_.*', '', names(tmp))),
                function(x) do.call(pmax, c(x, na.rm = TRUE))))

result

#  Date  Place Plane
#1  One   azea Three
#2  Two ertert  ertt
```

Comment: It's weird that `split.default` doesn't have any documentation! Such a fantastic function.